# How to pass dynamic param into decorators?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, decorator

Example:

```
       function adminOnly(user) {
            return function(target) {
                if (!user.isAdmin) {
                    console.error('You do not have sufficient 
privileges for this area!');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }


        class Appq {
            @adminOnly({ isAdmin: true })
            static getName(){
                console.log('func is execute');
            }
        }

    Appq.getName();
```

But in this case I pass `{ isAdmin: true }` how dynamic pass variables into decorators ?

- only use global vars into decorators ?
- can I pass args into decorators from  class methods ?

-I found some trick is use arguments

```
   return function(target, name, descriptor ) {
        console.log(arguments);
```

Comment: i don't know if that may help you but here is a link to it : https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-decorators-what-they-are/ . there's a `@log('some tag')` it may help

Comment: What do you mean? That inside your decorator you would like to access a prop of the class instance for example?

Comment: I need access to params which passed into method